# Unable to read reg_sz with Visual Basic Net /Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

This is the path to the key in the registry:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\appname.EXE\shell\open\command
```

There is a key

Default    Type:REG_SZ with this content:

```
"D:\programs\entry1\entry 2\appname.EXE" "%1"
```

How can I get "D:\programs\entry1\entry 2\appname.EXE" in a string? I am not able to do this with the usual methods, I guess this caused by the reg_sz type?

Comment: Use the [correct RegistryView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`REG_SZ` contains a string-value, so you should be able to get the (default)-value like this:

```
Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\appname.EXE\shell\open\command", False)
Dim s As String = regKey.GetValue("", "<value not found>").ToString
```

Or if another value is needed then just change the following line:

```
Dim s As String = regKey.GetValue("anothervalue", "<value not found>").ToString
```

Comment: Hi MatSnow, This line
Dim s As String = regKey.GetValue("", "<value not found>").ToString
ends in

Exception Unhandled
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
regKey was Nothing.

I think the reason is the (Default) entry as name.

Thanks for thinking along,

Juergen

Comment: @Juergen This exception occurs if the key does not exist.

Comment: Shame on me, sorry. Thank for your fast help! Juergen